# What is an answer for ごめんなさい？

Tags: word-choice

There must be an appropriate response, when the term is used. Thank you.

Comment: @FelipeOliveira Please write answers in the answer box :-)

Comment: @snailplane but sometimes i'm afraid my ansewer is not good enough, so I give a "hint" of what could be right, not sure if i should do that or not

Comment: @FelipeOliveira Posting answers as comments takes away the ability to downvote them.  If you're worried that the answer might not be good enough, taking away the ability to downvote is exactly the opposite of what we want to do.  If you'd like, you can discuss potential answers in [chat] before posting and get some feedback that way.

Comment: @snailplane I see, I'll do it that way from now on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

大丈夫(だ/です)よ -> it's alright. 構わない/構いません ->  i don't mind. (もう)いい -> it's (already) good. ううん/いいえ -> don't mention it. こちらこそ -> so am(it should be me saying...) i. Would be plausible I guess...